# Run y with a 1st order AR process in an OLS

Tags: r, regression, autoregressive-models

I have a regression: *yt=β1+β2*xi+ei*, with n=23, and "x" an AR(1):

*xi = c + ∅x(i-1) + ηi , where ηi~N(0,1) , x0~N(c/(1-∅),1/(1-∅^2) , c=2 , ∅=0.6*

The first part, creating x is OK  :

```
n = 23
phi <- 0.6
c <- 2
e <- as.vector(rnorm(n))
ni <- as.vector(rnorm(n))
x0 <- rnorm(1,(c/(1-phi)),(1/(1-(phi)^2)))

x <- rep(0,n)
x[1] <- c + phi*x0 + n[1]
for(i in 2:23){
  x[i] <- c + phi*x[i-1] + ni[i]
  }
```

How can i create y using this regression : ***yt=β1+β2*xi+ei***

and β1=0.913 and β2= 0.015

Comment: what's wrong with `beta1=0.913; beta2=0.015; y <- beta1+beta2*x + e` ?

Comment: just random numbers to use in the function

Comment: I mean, does my code solve your problem, or am I missing something?

Comment: Actually i need to run a loop a 1000 times for _e_ and _y_ , after that estimate beta using ols